# Extract all matches in a string using REGEXEXTRACT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a cell with values like so: `aasdf123asdf34asdf3`

I want to extract all groups of consecutive numbers: `123`, `34`, and `3`.

I think this is the regular expression I need: `(\d+)`.

But it is only extracting the first match.

This works outside of Google Sheets. Not sure why I can't get it to work in Google Sheets.

https://regexr.com/572et

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try actually generating the CSV string you want directly, using [`REGEXREPLACE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098245?hl=en):

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE("aasdf123asdf34asdf3", "\D+", ","), "^,|,$", "")
```

The inner call to `REGEXREPLACE` replaces all clusters of non digit characters with comma.  The outer call then removed any leading/trailing commas which the first replacement might have left behind.

[image: Sample of REGEXREPLACE]

---

Moreover you can use [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to separate the values into each individual cell:

```
=TRANSPOSE( SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE("aasdf123asdf34asdf3", "\D+", ","), "^,|,$", ""), ","))
```

[image: Sample with SPLIT]

In here the [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) function is just to stack the matches vertically instead of horizontally as `SPLIT` would lay them as default.